# Can be convert String value into integer which contains special character String like:(20+30+20)/45*100 any solution?

Tags: string, integer

Hi I am facing an issue while converting string value to integer. Actually I am converting String value into integer which contains special character String like:(20+30+20)/45*100 any solution?

Comment: You have to implement a parser to parse the expressions allowed, and then an evaluator which evaluates the expressions to generate a result. It's not trivial in any language.

Comment: can u please give an example actually i am doing this first time.

Comment: First please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And as mentioned this is not a trivial subject or suitable for beginners. You need to know your chosen language well, and you need to know many algorithms and data structures well too.

Comment: Thank you for your help i done this actually i was doing that type of expression first time but i have knowledge in android programming language of 3yrs so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myNum= "(20+30+20)/45*100"
parseInt(myNum.replace(/\D/g,''));
```

Comment: finally i got the solution which can parse and evaluate any type of expression https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/how-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Comment: depends on the language used